# Dropping the last comma in a macro

Tags: c++, templates

I am using the X macro pattern to keep a bunch of arrays/items in sync, and I want to create an argument list from it, however I can't work out a way to get a well formed list.  Here's what I mean:

```
#define MY_DATA \
    X(var_one, e_one, 1) \
    X(var_two, e_two, 2) \
    X(var_three, e_three, 3) \

#define X(a,b,c) b,
enum MyNumbers {
    MY_DATA
};
#undef X

#define X(a,b,c) c,
int MyValues[] = {
    MY_DATA
};
#undef X

void my_func(int a, int b, int c) {} // example do-nothing proc

void main(void)
{
    int var_one = MyValues[e_one];
    int var_two = MyValues[e_two];
    int var_three = MyValues[e_three];

#define X(a,b,c) a,

    my_func(MY_DATA);  // this fails because of the trailing comma

#undef X
}
```

Macros are not really my forte, so I can't think of a way of getting rid of the final comma in the function call.  Can anyone think of a way to stop it?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is: stop (ab)using macros.

Comment: That's a *pattern*? Where is it described?

Comment: @GregHewgill: [It's been used for almost 60 years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro), often for generating enum-to-string conversions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks, I've seen similar things once or twice but had no idea it had a name. Looks awful. :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [Boost Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library for “preprocessor metaprogramming tools including repetition and recursion.”

Even if you don't use their complete package, the chapter I linked to explains some techniques, specifically including iteration to build data structures and statements.

Here's an idea:  write

```
my_func(MY_DATA 0);
```

and declare my_func to take an extra (ignored) argument.

```
void my_func(int a, int b, int c, int)
```

Comment: This is more like a comment tbh.

Comment: Yes, the extra argument approach works, but I played with this approach, and it has two unfortunate drawbacks, 1: the call looks odd, and a maintainer is probably going to drop a comma and spend ages wondering why it doesn't work, and 2: I need to modify or shim all the function calls. I think I am going to go back to the drawing board on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I use a variant of this pattern frequently. However, it is normally used to define mappings between data. Along the lines of this:

```
MESSAGE(10, "Some error message"),
MESSAGE(11, "Som other error message"),
```

What des not make sense in your approach is that typically these constructs are used for large numbers of entries (100s, 1000s). You normally do not want that many arguments to a function.

If you really want to follow the approach, you could add another MACRO

#define MY_DATA \
    X(var_one, e_one, 1) COMMA \
    X(var_two, e_two, 2) COMMA \
    X(var_three, e_three, 3) \

and define comma as needed when you define X. (Or you could just put the comma in directly).

Comment: This would work, but it is slowly getting more and more complex.  I think I may need to re-assess how I am doing this.

Comment: If you could define an array of structures, you could pass that (a pointer) to the function rather than each element individually.

Comment: The main use I have is to pass a list of attributes to a function, and in some of these the values are set.  This makes using a structure more difficult.  Also the number of arguments is different for different classes.

Comment: I think you would be better off doing that as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

```
void my_func(int a, int b, int c, int dummy) {}
```

// ...

```
my_func(MY_DATA 0);
```

If you can't change `my_func` then make a thunk (i.e. an intermediate function that calls my_func)

A second option would be to include the comma in the `MY_DATA` macro instead of in `X`:

```
#define MY_DATA \
  X(var_one, e_one, 1), \
  X(var_two, e_two, 2), \
  X(var_three, e_three, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I played with this approach, and it has two unfortunate drawbacks, 1: the call looks odd, and a maintainer is probably going to drop a comma and spend ages wondering why it doesn't work, and 2: I need to modify or shim all the function calls.  I think I am going to go back to the drawing board on this one.

Comment: You don't need to modify all the function calls, just use an intermediate function.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant be "shim" them.  There are actually a few.